# Access Gradle Command Line -P Variables in Android Build

Tags: android, command-line, build, gradle

First of all I am new to gradle so this might be a stupid question but I was not able to find a solution.
I am trying to build a signed Android .apk file in the terminal and I want to use the command line in order to pass some arguments:

```
gradle assembleRelease -PkeyPw='secret123' -PstorePw='secret123' -PkeyAlias='My-Testkey' -PkeyLocation='/home/someUser/test-key.keystore'
```

Now I want to use these Variables inside the build.gradle file:

```
signingConfigs {
   release {
      storeFile $keyLocation
      storePassword $storePw
      keyAlias $keyAlias
      keyPassword $keyPw
   }
}
```

But they are null (Probably because it does not make any sense at all, but I did not find out how to do this).

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

I run the gradle build from java using the command

```
new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO.command(cmd).start
```

and get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 
* Where: 
Build file 'somePlace/app/build.gradle' line: 16 
* What went wrong: 
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. 
> Could not find property 'keyLocation' on project ':app'. 
* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All properties passed via `-P` switch are accessible via `project` variable. So it will be:

```
signingConfigs {
   release {
      storeFile project.keyLocation
      storePassword project.storePw
      keyAlias project.keyAlias
      keyPassword project.keyPw
   }
}
```

It's good idea to check if `project` has specified property before using it (to avoid problems):

```
signingConfigs {
   release {
      storeFile project.hasProperty('keyLocation') ? project.keyLocation : 'default'
      storePassword project.hasProperty('storePw') ? project.storePw : 'default'
      keyAlias project.hasProperty('keyAlias') ? project.keyAlias : 'default'
      keyPassword project.hasProperty('keyPw') ? project.keyPw : 'default'
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have. Is it possible that the problem is there because I run the gradle build from Java? I will add some details above. Give me 2 minutes ;)

Comment: Okay, it was a problem with the java part, too. I passed the arguments in a wrong way. Thanks for your help, after the gradle file was correct only the java part was left as a possible source. ;)

Comment: In the second snipped `keyLocation` is used as value for all properties. Looks like you forgot to change it after copy & paste :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to handle this is to override the values in your `build.gradle` file.

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file='/home/someUser/test-key.keystore' -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password='secret123' -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias='My-Testkey' -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password='secret123'
```

This requires no special code in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work via command line. Also is a very partial answer as it doesn't say where to put this for the different build variants.